# Bad request with response code 400, when posting json data to rest api using okHttp 4.*

Tags: java, okhttp, sharepoint-online

**goal** : I'm using sharepoint REST APIs to create a *list* in my sharepoint site. In this case I'm using okHttp as my Http library.

**expected result** : should return 201 as response code when calling the request using okHttp.

**actual result** :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: unexpected code Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=https://***.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists}
    at com.**.list.ListImpl.createAList(ListImpl.java:39)
    at com.**.Test.main(Test.java:16)
```

---

following are the steps I have implemented:

1. create a bearer token
2. set the required headers in the request
3. create a object of type which I want to send
4. serialize the object to json, so that data will be send as json data.

I have used the postman to test the API. It worked fine , got the desired result.

I have debugged the code, expected values were successfully assigned to the respective variables as well.

I know that 400 bad request means , there is something wrong with JSON data and server couldn't parse the json which I'm sending.
Eventhough I tried , but couldn't find the way to resolve this.
Any help would be appreciated.

---

following are the code samples.

ListImple.java

```
package com.****.list;

import com.**.app.properties.ApplicationProperties;
import com.**.metadata.MetaData;
import com.**.rest.TokenService;
import okhttp3.*;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ListImpl implements List {

    private String api ="/lists";
    private MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    @Override
    public void createAList(String token) throws IOException {
        MetaData metaData = new MetaData("SP.List");
        ListModel listData = new ListModel(metaData,true,104,
                true,"sample description 02", "list-number-02");

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(listData);
        String data = jsonObject.toString();

        RequestBody formBody = RequestBody.create(data, JSON);
        System.out.println(formBody.contentType());

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(ApplicationProperties.getBaseUrl() + api)
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose")
                .addHeader("accept", "application/json;odata=verbose")
                .addHeader("X-RequestDigest", "0x87D8893C3016E8E7EB288E13276DE7C8D5250EC26025FDADCF9A3E6C86DF0C4A5EC86B3B4AEAD882E06058BC0919A61E10C3DEFDE3B275E67698A9E1B4456CEF")
                .post(formBody)
                .build();
        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
            if(!response.isSuccessful()) {
                throw new IOException("unexpected code " + response);
            }
            System.out.println(response.body().string());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have encountered this kind of errors where it gives 400. Most of them I feel are due to not setting the proper content type or accept headers. Please verify if you need to change any of : `Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose")` or `.addHeader("accept", "application/json;odata=verbose")`

Comment: @SantosshKumhar I have omitted both odata=verbose part from the above two header, and still the same bad request error gave me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of debugging I came to conclusion that problem was OkHttp rest library.
So I removed that library and included the `org.apache.httpcomponents` artifact in the pom.xml file.
now All are working fine.